# How to alert on slack about a HTTP request if it takes more time to complete than specific time

Tags: slack, newrelic, nrql

I have a http request. `https://server:port//get_somthing?x=10`.

Assume that it is expected to respond within 1 second. I notice this in newrelic that, sometimes it takes 1.5, 2 seconds. I would like to look into the logs and investigate whenever it takes more time than 1 second. So I want to set up alerts on a slack channel whenever request takes more time than the prescribed time.

How to achieve this?? I am using newrelic's java agent.

Comment: Have you checked out the official Slack app for New Relic in the app store? https://slack.com/apps/A0F827KK2-new-relic

Comment: However, if you are asking how to build an app with this functionality I am afraid your question is way too broad for this forum.